# Suppressing a trailing "." in numerical output from Mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

Is there some straightforward way to ensure that, when converted to strings, approximate numbers (i.e., numbers with the `Real` head) won't have a trailing "."? I would like it if they were to only have the decimal point in cases where there's actually a displayed fractional part.

The solutions I've found are not robust, and depend on using `Precision` and `Accuracy` together `NumberForm` in an awkward way, or using `RealDigits` in an even more awkward way.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've used this in the past when displaying numbers in figures:

```
Integerise[x_] := If[Round[x] == x, ToString[Round@x] <> ".0", ToString@x]
```

Just remove `<> ".0"` if you don't want integers to be displayed with a zero decimal.

**Update:** As mentioned by dreeves in the comment, `ToString` will still truncate a number within 0.0001 or so of an integer and display the dot.

A better way to remove the trailing dot is to use the `Inputform` format for ToString:

```
NormalNumber[x_] := ToString[x, InputForm]
```

with a test:

```
NormalNumber /@ {5, 5.5, 123.001, 123.0001}
```

This could be incorporated into `Integerise` above to fix the problem noted.

Comment: I just tried this and found that it breaks for Integerise[123.0001] (it returns a string ending with a trailing ".").

Answer (score 4):

I recommend this:

```
shownum[x_] := StringReplace[ToString@NumberForm[x, ExponentFunction->(Null&)], 
                             RegularExpression["\\.$"]->""]
```

It just does a regex search&replace on the trailing ".".  If you want "123." to display as "123.0" instead of "123" then just replace that final empty string with ".0".

UPDATE: My original version displayed wrong for numbers that Mathematica by default displays in scientific notation.
I fixed that with NumberForm.

Here's the version I actually use in real life. It allows for optional rounding:

```
(* Show Number. Convert to string w/ no trailing dot. Round to the nearest r. *)
Unprotect[Round];   Round[x_,0] := x;   Protect[Round];
re = RegularExpression;
shn[x_, r_:0] := StringReplace[
  ToString@NumberForm[Round[N@x,r], ExponentFunction->(Null&)], re@"\\.$"->""]
```

Comment: This plays the role of removeTrailingDot in my answer. Also, though I'm of course a huge fan of regex, it's faster to do direct string manipulation - check the last character and drop it if it's ".". The regex is quicker to customize, of course, and perhaps speed isn't an issue - but this kind of function can get called repeatedly a lot. (You could also compile the function - don't know off the top of my head if that works with regex)

Answer (score 1):

I'd probably just post-process the string. It's faster (and way easier) to just check if the last character is "." than to do redundant arithmetic and take into account all the precision settings.

Edit: maybe you know this, but you can do something like this:

```
userToString[expr_, form___] := ToString[expr,form];

userToString[expr_Real, form___] := removeTrailingDot[ToString[expr,form]];
```

Answer (score 1):

The functions `NumberForm`, `ScientificForm`, `EngineeringForm`, etc. ... offers the option `NumberFormat` to format and arrange the mantissa, base and exponent of a number. With

```
numberTrim[expr_] := NumberForm[expr,
   NumberFormat -> (Row[{StringTrim[#1, "."], 
        If[#3 == "", "", "\[ThinSpace]\[Times]\[ThinSpace]" <> #2^#3]}] &)];
```

the default Mathematica output is reproduced, but the trailing dot is removed.