# Show a number with specified number of significant digits

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, utilities

I use the following function to convert a number to a string for display purposes (don't use scientific notation, don't use a trailing dot, round as specified):

```
(* Show Number. Convert to string w/ no trailing dot. Round to the nearest r. *)
Unprotect[Round];   Round[x_,0] := x;   Protect[Round];
shn[x_, r_:0] := StringReplace[
  ToString@NumberForm[Round[N@x,r], ExponentFunction->(Null&)], re@"\\.$"->""]
```

(Note that `re` is an alias for `RegularExpression`.)

That's been serving me well for years.
But sometimes I don't want to specify the number of digits to round to, rather I want to specify a number of significant figures.
For example, 123.456 should display as 123.5 but 0.00123456 should display as 0.001235.

To get really fancy, I might want to specify significant digits both before and after the decimal point.
For example, I might want .789 to display as 0.8 but 789.0 to display as 789 rather than 800.

Do you have a handy utility function for this sort of thing, or suggestions for generalizing my function above?

Related: [Suppressing a trailing "." in numerical output from Mathematica](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1545986/suppressing-a-trailing)

**UPDATE:** I tried asking a general version of this question here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5627185/displaying-numbers-to-non-technical-users

Comment: Perhaps what I really want is to specify a precision of however many digits there are left of the decimal point, plus n. I'll post as an answer whatever I end up using; hopefully it will be useful to someone else.

Comment: Regarding showing n significant figures: Doesn't regular old NumberForm do what you want? NumberForm[123.456, 4] gives 123.5 and NumberForm[0.00123456, 4] gives 0.001235. If not, can you specify the behavior you want in more detail?

Comment: Regarding specifying significant figures "both before and after the decimal point"... Can you explain the exact behavior you want here, perhaps with some more examples?

Comment: Hmm, NumberForm isn't quite what I want since I want 0.1234 to display as .12 but 1234 as 1234, not 1200. I guess I want the number of significant figures to depend on how many digits are left of the decimal point. Maybe what I'm really after is just "suppress the extra, over-precise digits after the decimal point".

Comment: How about this: I want to specify n digits of precision but clipped to be between il and il+m, where il is the number of digits in the integer part.  Maybe m is 2 if I never want more than 2 significant digits to the right of the decimal point and n might be 4 if I want to drop the decimal part altogether for numbers over 1000.

Comment: So it sounds like you first need to determine how many digits are to the left, then adjust your precision based on that and your required significant digits. You can use Min, Max or conditionals to compute that precision.

Comment: Thanks for all the help, everyone! My solution is doing what I wanted now. Would it be annoying if I totally rewrote this question, basically deleting everything above the "UPDATE"? I'd like to make this more useful for future visitors.

Comment: Some acknowledgment that there was an earlier version would be good, so that my orphan doesn't look too wrong.  I still think my shn2 function is useful for formatting, just not your specific needs.

Answer (score 5):

dreeves, I think I finally understand what you want, and you already had it, pretty much.  If not, please try again to explain what I am missing.

```
shn2[x_, r_: 0] := 
 StringReplace[
  ToString@NumberForm[x, r, ExponentFunction -> (Null &)], 
  RegularExpression@"\\.0*$" -> ""]
```

Testing:

```
shn2[#, 4] & /@ {123.456, 0.00123456}
shn2[#, {3, 1}] & /@ {789.0, 0.789}
shn2[#, {10, 2}] & /@ {0.1234, 1234.}
shn2[#, {4, 1}] & /@ {12.34, 1234.56}

Out[1]= {"123.5", "0.001235"}

Out[2]= {"789", "0.8"}

Out[3]= {"0.12", "1234"}

Out[4]= {"12.3", "1235"}
```

Comment: +1. Nice. It seems you deleted an answer that received one upvote and then created this new one. It's usually better to edit the old answer content, except very seldom, when you want to keep two very different answers.

Comment: @belisarius Sorry.  Does that mean my deleted answer is still visible to everybody, and not just me?  Is there a list of site guidelines that I overlooked?  Also, is there any way to send private messages?  I know about chat, but that requires users to be on-line simultaneously.

Comment: Your deleted answers are visible to people with more than 10K rep points only. Your "contact by chat" may be related to [this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78352/practical-method-to-answer-contact-requests-in-questions-using-se-chat). As for private messages the answer is simple: No. The guidelines, etc etc are [here](http://tinyurl.com/2vycnvr) and in the [meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions) site in general (LOTS of content).

Answer (score 1):

This may not be the complete answer (you need to convert from/to string), but this function takes arguments a number `x` and significant figures `sig` wanted. The number of digits it keeps is the maximum of `sig` or the number of digits to the left of the decimal.

```
A[x_,sig_]:=NumberForm[x, Max[Last[RealDigits[x]], sig]]
```

[RealDigits](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/RealDigits.html)

Comment: Cool, thanks. The Clip part of my answer tries to generalize this a bit. I used IntegerLength@IntegerPart because Last@RealDigits can be negative.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a possible generalization of my original function.
(I've determined that it's not equivalent to Mr Wizard's solution but I'm not sure yet which I think is better.)

```
re = RegularExpression;

(* Show Number. Convert to string w/ no trailing dot. Use at most d significant
   figures after the decimal point. Target t significant figures total (clipped 
   to be at least i and at most i+d, where i is the number of digits in integer 
   part of x). *)
shn[x_, d_:5, t_:16] := ToString[x]
shn[x_?NumericQ, d_:5, t_:16] := With[{i= IntegerLength@IntegerPart@x},
  StringReplace[ToString@NumberForm[N@x, Clip[t, {i,i+d}],
                                    ExponentFunction->(Null&)],
                re@"\\.$"->""]]
```

#### Testing:

Here we specify 4 significant digits, but never dropping any to the left of the decimal point and never using more than 2 significant digits to the right of the decimal point.

```
(# -> shn[#, 2, 4])& /@ 
  {123456, 1234.4567, 123.456, 12.345, 1.234, 1.0001, 0.123, .0001234}

{  123456 -> "123456", 
 1234.456 -> "1234", 
  123.456 -> "123.5"
   12.345 -> "12.35", 
    1.234 -> "1.23", 
   1.0001 -> "1", 
    0.123 -> "0.12", 
0.0001234 -> "0.00012" }
```

Comment: @MrWizard: Suppose I want 12.34 to display as 12.3 but 1234.56 to display as 1235. I'm basically saying I want 1 digit to the right of the decimal point unless there are already enough significant digits to the left.  (Thanks for your help with this!)

Comment: @dreeves that case is handled correctly.  See `Out[4]` under "Testing" in my answer.

Comment: Ah, sorry, how about shn2[.000123, {3,2}]? I don't want to ever display tiny numbers as zero, yet also never replace significant digits left of the decimal point with zeroes. I believe your shn2 can't do both of those with the same parameter settings? Check out the desiderata I just appended to the question. Thanks again, and sorry for this terribly ill-posed question!

Comment: @dreeves sorry for answering the wrong question three times!  I guess you have your solution now?  Are modifications to `Clip` really needed, or can you just use `shn[x_?NumericQ, d_: 1*^6, t_: 1*^6]` since I cannot imagine needing more than one million digits?

Comment: @MrWizard: Totally my fault! Really appreciate the help. Ah, good idea for avoiding the modifications to Clip, though I kind of thought those modifications were good regardless.

Comment: Is there any reason to leave up the `Clip` modifications now that you edited out the instances of `Infinity`?  To me that is just confusing at this point.